# elasticsearch connector doesn't work - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, strimzi

Kafka elasticsearch connector "confluentinc-kafka-connect-elasticsearch-5.5.0" doesn't work on-prem.

```
"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet\n\tat io.searchbox.client.AbstractJestClient.<init>(AbstractJestClient.java:38)\n\tat io.searchbox.client.http.JestHttpClient.<init>(JestHttpClient.java:43)\n\tat io.searchbox.client.JestClientFactory.getObject(JestClientFactory.java:51)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.jest.JestElasticsearchClient.<init>(JestElasticsearchClient.java:149)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.jest.JestElasticsearchClient.<init>(JestElasticsearchClient.java:141)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkTask.start(ElasticsearchSinkTask.java:122)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkTask.start(ElasticsearchSinkTask.java:51)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.initializeAndStart(WorkerSinkTask.java:305)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:184)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:234)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\n"
```

I'm using also mssql connector and s3 connector plugins in the same path; they work but elasticsearch plugin gives noclassfound error. This is my folder structure in worker:

```
[kafka@mssql-minio-connect-cluster-connect-d9859784f-ffj8r plugins]$ ls
confluentinc-kafka-connect-elasticsearch-5.5.0  confluentinc-kafka-connect-s3-5.5.0  debezium-connector-sqlserver  kafka-connect-shell-sink-5.1.0
[kafka@mssql-minio-connect-cluster-connect-d9859784f-ffj8r plugins]$ ls -l
total 16
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4096 May 25 22:15 confluentinc-kafka-connect-elasticsearch-5.5.0
drwxrwxr-x 5 root root 4096 May 15 02:26 confluentinc-kafka-connect-s3-5.5.0
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4096 May 15 02:26 debezium-connector-sqlserver
drwxrwxr-x 4 root root 4096 May 15 02:26 kafka-connect-shell-sink-5.1.0
[kafka@mssql-minio-connect-cluster-connect-d9859784f-ffj8r plugins]$ ls debezium-connector-sqlserver
debezium-api-1.1.1.Final.jar  debezium-connector-sqlserver-1.1.1.Final.jar  debezium-core-1.1.1.Final.jar  mssql-jdbc-7.2.2.jre8.jar
[kafka@mssql-minio-connect-cluster-connect-d9859784f-ffj8r plugins]$ ls confluentinc-kafka-connect-s3-5.5.0
assets  etc  lib  manifest.json
[kafka@mssql-minio-connect-cluster-connect-d9859784f-ffj8r plugins]$ ls confluentinc-kafka-connect-elasticsearch-5.5.0 -l
total 8356
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   17558 May 25 11:53 common-utils-5.5.0.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  263965 May 25 11:53 commons-codec-1.9.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   61829 May 25 11:53 commons-logging-1.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   79845 May 25 19:34 compress-lzf-1.0.3.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  241622 May 25 11:53 gson-2.8.5.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2329410 May 25 19:34 guava-18.0.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1140290 May 25 19:34 hppc-0.7.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  179335 May 25 11:53 httpasyncclient-4.1.3.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  747794 May 25 11:53 httpclient-4.5.3.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  323824 May 25 11:53 httpcore-4.4.6.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  356644 May 25 11:53 httpcore-nio-4.4.6.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  280996 May 25 19:34 jackson-core-2.8.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   22191 May 25 11:53 jest-6.3.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  276130 May 25 11:53 jest-common-6.3.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  621992 May 25 19:34 joda-time-2.8.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   62226 May 25 19:34 jsr166e-1.1.0.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   83179 May 25 11:53 kafka-connect-elasticsearch-5.5.0.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1330394 May 25 19:34 netty-3.10.5.Final.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   41139 May 25 11:53 slf4j-api-1.7.26.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   49754 May 25 19:34 t-digest-3.0.jar
[kafka@mssql-minio-connect-cluster-connect-d9859784f-ffj8r plugins]$
```

I've read some messages there are missing jar files / dependencies in the elasticsearch connector, I added them as you can see above but no luck.

This is my connector config:

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1alpha1
kind: KafkaConnector
metadata:
  name: "elastic-files-connector"
  labels:
    strimzi.io/cluster: mssql-minio-connect-cluster
spec:
  class: io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector
  config:
    connection.url: "https://escluster-es-http.dev-kik.io:9200"
    connection.username: "${file:/opt/kafka/external-configuration/elasticcreds/connector.properties:connection.username}"
    connection.password: "${file:/opt/kafka/external-configuration/elasticcreds/connector.properties:connection.password}"
    flush.timeout.ms: 10000
    max.buffered.events: 20000
    batch.size: 2000
    topics: filesql1.dbo.Files
    tasks.max: '1'
    type.name: "_doc"
    max.request.size: "536870912"
    key.converter: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
    key.converter.schema.registry.url: http://schema-registry-cp-schema-registry:8081
    value.converter: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
    value.converter.schema.registry.url: http://schema-registry-cp-schema-registry:8081
    internal.key.converter: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
    internal.value.converter: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
    key.converter.schemas.enable: true
    value.converter.schemas.enable: true
    schema.compatibility: NONE    
    errors.tolerance: all
    errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name: "dlq_filesql1.dbo.Files"
    errors.deadletterqueue.context.headers.enable: "true"
    errors.log.enable: "true"
    behavior.on.null.values: "ignore"
    errors.retry.delay.max.ms: 60000
    errors.retry.timeout: 300000
    behavior.on.malformed.documents: warn
```

I changed username/password as plaintext; no luck.
I tried for both http/https for elasticsearch connection, no luck.

This is my elasticsearch srv information:

```
devadmin@vdi-mk2-ubn:~/kafka$ kubectl get svc -n elastic-system
NAME                     TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)          AGE
elastic-webhook-server   ClusterIP      10.104.95.105   <none>           443/TCP          21h
escluster-es-default     ClusterIP      None            <none>           <none>           8h
escluster-es-http        LoadBalancer   10.108.69.136   192.168.215.35   9200:31214/TCP   8h
escluster-es-transport   ClusterIP      None            <none>           9300/TCP         8h
kibana-kb-http           LoadBalancer   10.102.81.206   192.168.215.34   5601:31315/TCP   20h
devadmin@vdi-mk2-ubn:~/kafka$
```

I can connec to to elastic search services from Kafka Connect Worker by the both ways:

```
[kafka@mssql-minio-connect-cluster-connect-d9859784f-ffj8r plugins]$ curl -u "elastic:5NM0Pp25sFzNu578873BWFnN" -k "https://10.108.69.136:9200"
{
  "name" : "escluster-es-default-0",
  "cluster_name" : "escluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "TP5f4MGcSn6Dt9hZ144tEw",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.7.0",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "81a1e9eda8e6183f5237786246f6dced26a10eaf",
    "build_date" : "2020-05-12T02:01:37.602180Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.5.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
[kafka@mssql-minio-connect-cluster-connect-d9859784f-ffj8r plugins]$ curl -u "elastic:5NM0Pp25sFzNu578873BWFnN" -k "https://escluster-es-http.dev-kik.io:9200"
{
  "name" : "escluster-es-default-0",
  "cluster_name" : "escluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "TP5f4MGcSn6Dt9hZ144tEw",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.7.0",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "81a1e9eda8e6183f5237786246f6dced26a10eaf",
    "build_date" : "2020-05-12T02:01:37.602180Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.5.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
[kafka@mssql-minio-connect-cluster-connect-d9859784f-ffj8r plugins]$
```

no matter what I do, exception never changes at all. I don't know there is something else which I can try. My brain is burning, I'm about to get crazy.

Am I missing anything or could you please advise how you guys run this connector on-prem on Kubernetes?

Thanks & regards

Comment: How are you installing the connector in your Kafka Connect worker?

Comment: I use "Strimzi Kafka Operator" to deploy the connector.

Comment: I'd get it working standalone first, and then try and get it working with Strimzi.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using `kafka_2. 12-2.5.0` and I had the same problem. I've noticed that guava jar is missing in $KAFKA_HOME/libs with respect to Kafka `2. 4.0`. As a workaround, I copied the jar manually (`guava-20.0. jar`) from the previous Kafka distribution and everything worked.

Comment: Adding missing `guava-20.0.jar` to `/opt/kafka/libs/` at worker node container fixes the problem. My environment is;
Strimzi 0.18
Kafka 2.5.0

    COPY guava-20.0.jar /opt/kafka/libs/

Comment: I think guava _used to be_ a dependency of Kafka until 2.4.0, but no longer is. Thus you would need to include it in you kafka connect image, since it's no longer in the base image. The bigger question for me is how this ever worked since I would have thought the Kafka Connect classpath isolation should have preventing you using Kafka's guava.

Comment: you can download it from here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/20.0

Answer (score 0):

If you use a connector, make sure you load its dependencies as well.

See https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/issues/588#issuecomment-1407751798